# await not working for async wait fetch to redirect a page

Tags: javascript, redirect, async-await

trying to direct to external url by fetch
front end side:

```
var params
urlFetch(new_url)
        .then(params=function() {
           var obj=decodeFormParams(params)
console.log("decode value is " + obj); ...
```

backend side:

```
export function urlFetch(url ) {
  console.log(url );
  const request = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST', // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
    mode: 'no-cors', // no-cors, *cors, same-origin
    credentials: 'omit', // include, *same-origin, omit
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8 ',
       "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
    },

   // body: JSON.stringify() // body data type must match "Content-Type" header
  }).then(await function(Response)  {

    if (Response.ok) {
      return Response.text();

    }
    else {
      return Promise.reject("Fetch did not succeed");
    }
  } )
  }
}
```

CONSOLE.LOG IS:

```
https://icom.yaad.net/cgi-bin/yaadpay/yaadpay3new.pl?action=pay&PassP=pb&Masof=4500563228&sendemail=True&UTF8=True&UTF8out=True&ClientName=ASG&ClientLName=Shg&cell=&email=SGD&Amount=500&Info=%D7%91%D7%99%D7%AA%20%D7%97%D7%91%22%D7%93%20%D7%A7%D7%A1%D7%A8%20%D7%93%D7%99%D7%95%D7%95%D7%99&tmp=8&Coin=1&PageLang=HEB&Postpone=False&Tash=36&FixTash=True&SendHesh=True
returend value is function params() {
    console.log("returend value is " + _params);
    var obj = decodeFormParams(_params);
    console.log("decode value is " + obj);
```

AS YOU CAN SEE THE URL IS CORRECT AND SUPPOSE TO REDIRECT TO THAT PAGE BUT NOTING HAPPENDS AND THE FUNCTION DOESNT WAIT
If IT DIDNT WORK WhY IM NOT GETTING THE LOG OF THE ERROR:

```
else {
      return Promise.reject("Fetch did not succeed");
```

im sending parameters to a page for payment system and the user has to fill the card info there and if it succeeds i should get code=0 as results but nothing hapends